# Can you mix bootstrap 3.3 and bootstrap 4.1? I have tried and it breaks the website

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use bootstrap and twitter bootstrap at the same time. Basically, I can't seem to get them to work together. Are they even supposed to work together? You can see the js Fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/paralaxwombat/v7hpoc6m/4/

There are two sets of bootstrap call lines.

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />



  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If you remove one of them, the nav bar works and the bottom doesn't. If you remove the bottom the nav bar doesn't work but the bottom does.

I am wondering if there is a workaround.

Comment: There is only one Bootstrap. We don't know what you're referring to othen than you're mixing CDNs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap **is** Bootstrap. You are trying to mix version 3 and version 4.

They are not designed to work together. Bootstrap 4 is designed to completely replace Bootstrap 3.

Use version 4. Change the code which is following version 3 conventions to use version 4 conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use two different versions of the same library so I think the answer will be 'No'.

I don't know if there's a document with all the similarities and differences, but I know the [3.3 javascript api](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/) and the [4.1 javascript api](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/javascript/#programmatic-api) conflict.

Comment: *the similarities and differences*: they are simply different. Only the name is the same

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 versions of bootstrap and you are trying to use both of them at the same time. These are all versions of bootstrap [Versions](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/versions/). If you want to know more about them check [bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ver.asp).